# UITableView Delete Row Animation Glitch

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` that has a custom header view and some table view cells.

Both the header and the cells are generated using auto layout (programmatically **not** xib's) and I am using `UITableViewAutomaticaDimension` for both `heightForHeader...` and `heightForRowAtIndexP...`.

My trouble is that, unless I am deleting a cell that remains visible **without** having to scroll down, upon deleting a cell, I get a **very** awful animation glitch, which I have narrowed down to being caused from my header.

**IF** I remove my header, and simple return a blank slate

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return UIView.new;

}
```

the issue is resolved completely.

---

What I am having a hard time understanding is **why** is the table view so distraught when I have a header view in place? 
**FYI:** My header does not have any constraint issues that the debugger is telling me about, so I am not sure if it is an SDK bug or something I am missing....

If anyone has any thoughts I would much appreciate it..

Comment: Have you tried returning an explicit value for `heightForHeader...` (presuming your header is a fixed height)? I can't find the thread now, but I remember reading of problems with `UITableViewAutomaticaDimension` and tableview headers before. The use of `UITableViewAutomaticaDimension` for headers seems to be undocumented and, according to other posts I've seen, problematic.

Comment: The header will in fact stay constant so i will see what happens with that approach

Comment: Passing a constant doesnt work, but what *does* work is setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints= NO;` works. But that for some reason actually disrupts all of my constraints added thereafter (each with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to NO as well)